# How to setup a data layer so client apps can switch between environments without configuring the connection string?

Tags: .net, architecture, configuration

I have a core data library that provides the interface between client apps and the database. Of course, the data library must have a connection string to connect to the database.

Right now each client app.config or web.config contains the connection string(s), but it is redundant and seems inappropriate for the client to configure the data layer library.  The only thing I want the client to be able to do is request a certain mode for the data layer such as something like "mode = test|dev|live".

Also, in the future, the data layer may call a web service. At that point, the actual connection information could be on a separate server than the client, so how would the service be initialized to the appropriate mode?

Here are the various options I have considered:

1. Put the connection strings in an external config file and reference it from the client config, then use a separate config value to initialize the data layer in a specific mode.
   pros: the connection strings are in one place
   cons: the client still has to provide the link to the connection strings
2. Put the connection strings in the Machine.config, then use a separate config value to initialize the data layer in a specific mode
   pros: the connection strings are in one place; the client doesn't provide any information about the connections
   cons: the modes are tied to the connection string names in the Machine.config, and when the data layer is modified to call a service rather than the database directly, there is no way to tell the service which mode to use, because you can't initialize a stateless service in a specific mode.
3. Put connection information in the Machine.config. The connection information could be database connection strings or references to separate service endpoints--one for each mode. then use a separate config value to initialize the data layer in a specific mode.
   pros: the data layer configuration is in one place; the client doesn't provide any information about the configuration; the data layer can interpret the mode as a database connection or as a separate service endpoint.
   cons: would have to create separate services for each mode

Does the last option make the most sense? Is there another option, such as dependency injection or passing the mode to each data access method or something else? I see a couple other similar questions, but I am still looking for the right strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio 2010 has come up with new web.config transformation utility. Have you tried this? You can transform your web.config for different configuration settings like debug|Release|Test|Dev.

You can read more about this here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/10/13/common-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Hopes this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  This is essentially equivalent to option number one and would indeed provide a mechanism for altering either the connection string link or the mode for a web client, but I think the cons listed still apply.